# Can not uninstall Drupal Media Gallery Module 7.x-2.x-dev

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I accidentally installed the dev version of the Drupal Media Gallery module 7.x-2.x-dev, and now I can not uninstall it to get the current version.  It is not enabled, on the module page it has a grayed out box.  It does not show up on the uninstall list.

In the Requires list it shows this:

Media (>=2.x) (incompatible with version 7.x-1.4)

I am trying to make a video gallery.  I want to install the stable version Media Gallery 7.x-1.0.  Please advice me on the best way to do this.  I am a drupal amateur.  I've read a little about drush, but had a hard time using it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is better asked on [drupal.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am telling you the simplest way to uninstall the existing Media module and install your desired version of module.
Steps

1. Go to module list page. Path: http://example.com/?q=admin/modules
2. Uncheck your module and save.
3. Click on Uninstall tab (Path: http://example.com/?q=admin/modules/uninstall). You will find it(Media Gallery module 7.x-2.x-dev) in this list. Check and click on Uninstall button.
4. Download your desired version of the module.
5. unzip and keep the entire folder inside sites/all/modules/custom directory.
6. Go to module list page and look for your module.
7. Check and save.